# How to specify `SagaIterator` effect return type

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

I have a `SagaIterator` as below:

```
function* myStringSagaIterator(): SagaIterator {
  /* Safely create and yield some effects */

  return 'done!';
}
```

I then execute the above, say, within another `SagaIterator`:

```
function* runStuff(): SagaIterator {
  const result: number = yield call(myStringSagaIterator); // No error!
}
```

The above does not result in a type error, even though `myStringSagaIterator` will always return a `string` - better still, will always return `'done!'`. This is because `SagaIterator` internally explicitly types the effects result to `any`.

Is there any way to make this type safe?

Answer (score -1):

Check this [ongoing thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2983#issuecomment-230404301), tldr; it's a typescript limitation

Comment: IMO this is not an answer. Aside, would you say it's possible that `SagaIterator` could be made a Generic? In which case an issue should be opened I guess.